# Passing an array of values in Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to pass an array of values in `Url.Action`.

Currently I'm doing:

```
var redirectUrl = Url.Action("search", new {   
        q = criteria.Q,
        advanced = criteria.Advanced,
        salaryfrom = criteria.SalaryFrom,
        salaryto = criteria.SalaryTo,
    });

if (criteria.JobTypes != null)
    redirectUrl += criteria.JobTypes.Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, x) => a += "&jobTypes=" + x);
```

To give me something like:

```
/search?q=developer&advanced=false&salaryfrom=20000&salaryto=80000&jobTypes=Full%20Time&jobTypes=Contract
```

Is there a nicer/cleaner approach?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you "own" the controller?
If so, I'd serialize and deserialize the list as a comma separated string on each side.
It'd also be nice if criteria.JobTypes is an empty list instead of a possible null, then you don't need the ?? below.

```
var redirectUrl = Url.Action("search", new {
    // ...
    jobTypes = String.Join(criteria.JobTypes ?? new string[0], ",")
}
```

And do `jobTypes.split(",")` in the action.

URL would look a bit nicer too:

```
/search?q=developer&advanced=false&salaryfrom=20000&salaryto=80000&jobTypes=Full%20Time,Contract
```

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Lars-Erik's answer, you can also use the other overload, [the one that takes a dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492912.aspx).
This is also useful to construct e.g. an input that might or might not be disabled.

```
RouteValueDictionary args = new RouteValueDictionary {
    {"q", criteria.Q},
    {"advanced", criteria.Advanced},
    {"salaryfrom", criteria.SalaryFrom},
    {"salaryto", criteria.SalaryTo},
};
if(criteria.JobTypes != null) {
    // Either foreach the jobTypes or go Lars-Erik's way (nicer).
    args.Add("jobTypes", "foo");
}
```

Take care about special characters!
If you don't fully control the input, you might get a jobType "R&D" that will break your url: `/search?q=...&jobTypes=R&D` gets you `jobTypes=R`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the array elements individually to the RouteValueDictionary -- you just have to change the name to match the model binding name for round trip purposes.

The second argument to your action can be a RouteValueDictionary as ANeves said.

```
RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary { { "name", "value"}, ...};
int i = 0;
criteria.JobTypes.ForEach(v => rvd.Add(String.Format("jobTypes[{0}]", i++), (object) v));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Type Casting to 'object`or`object[]`or using`RouteValueDictionary`. A simple way to achieve the same is using “Newtonsoft.Json”

**If using .Net Core 3.0 or later;**

Default to using the built in `System.Text.Json` parser implementation.

```
@using System.Text.Json;

…….

@Url.Action(“ActionName”, “ControllerName”, new {object = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(‘@ModalObject’)  }))
```

**If stuck using .Net Core 2.2 or earlier;**

Default to using Newtonsoft JSON.Net as your first choice JSON Parser.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

…..

@Url.Action(“ActionName”, “ControllerName”, new {object = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(‘@ModalObject’)  }))
```

you may need to install the package first.

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then,

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string modalObjectJSON)
{
    Modal modalObj = new Modal();
    modalObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Modal>(modalObjectJSON);

}
```